# How to remove a selected value from an array in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsxg3/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var colorArray = new Array(
      "#ff0000",
      "#000000",
      "#00ff00",
      "#0000ff"
    );

    var randColor, randListElem;
    var listElems = $('li');

    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        //randColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*(colorArray.length));
        colorArray.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random();});
        var ran = colorArray.pop();
        randListElem = Math.floor(Math.random()*(listElems.length));
        $(listElems[randListElem]).css("background", colorArray[ran]);
    };
});
```

Once I run the last command in the loop I want to remove the color in colorArray from being used again. How can I do this?

Answer (score -2):

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/53qy2/5/)**

Since you're using jQuery

`colorArray.splice($.inArray(randColor, myarray), 1);`

If the item isn't in the array. Something a little better

```
var index = $.inArray(randColor, colorArray);
if (index>=0) colorArray.splice(index, 1);
```

Or

```
var itemtoRemove = randcolor;
arr.splice($.inArray(itemtoRemove, colorArray),1);
```